# php several pages include by ID

Tags: php

What's the right way to include two or three pages and include them by ID, like:
**index.php?page=one** will include **one.html**
and
**index.php?page=two** will include **two.html**
To same php page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both previous answers are vulnerable to file inclusion attacks, I would suggest a different approach using a predefined array of available pages to include:

```
<?php

    $pages = array('one'=>'one.php',
                   'two'=>'two.php');

    if(in_array($_GET['page'], array_keys($pages))) {
        // only include if the page is really defined in your $pages array
        include($pages[$_GET['page']]);
    } else {
        // don't include or simply include a default page here
        // include('default.php');
    }

?>
```

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Given the un-deniable points below, setting an array of allowed pages would be a good idea as well.

**URI:**

```
index.php?pages=one,two,three
```

**Script:**

```
$allowedPages = array('one', 'two', 'three');

if($_GET['pages']){
    foreach(explode(',', $_GET['pages']) as $page){
        if(file_exists($page.'.html') && in_array($page, $allowedPages)){
            include_once($page.'.html');
        }
    }
}
```

Or an array in the URI, keeping the `page` query string variable singular:

**URI:**

```
index.php?page[]=one&page[]=two&page[]=three
```

**Script:**

```
$allowedPages = array('one', 'two', 'three');

if($_GET['page']){
    foreach($_GET['page'] as $page){
        if(file_exists($page.'.html') && in_array($page, $allowedPages)){
            include_once($page.'.html');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: generally speaking, directly using user-supplied data in a filesystem operation is dangerous. your code allows pretty much **ANY** html file on the server to be included. consider `example.com/script.php?pages[]=../../../../../../../../seekrit_data`

Comment: When are secret data files stored with .html extensions?

Comment: never say never. not likely, but who knows. never ever directly use user-supplied data like this, even if your exact code only opens up html files. you WILL do this sort of things elsewhere, screw up, and open up your entire file system.

Comment: Not only `.html`. Using `%00` at the end might skip the concatenation of `.html` string when `magic_quotes_gpc` isn't enabled!

Comment: True.  Adjusted the answer.

Comment: To avoid the overhead of maintaining a list of legal filenames, you could also do a restrictive regex only allowing [A-Za-z0-9]*.

Comment: files name can contain some special characters aswell.. @ZsoltSzilagy please dont forget that.

Answer (score -1):

you will have to check if the file exists and that the `$_GET['page']` is a valid value

```
    <?php
    $pageName = $_GET['page'] . '.php';
    if(isset($pageName) && $pageName != '')
    {
        if(file_exists($pageName))
        {
            require_once($pageName);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Carefull, $pageName will be always set hence to line 1. First check isset($_GET['page'])), then do the rest.

Comment: Please have a carefull look that there is an && condition and not || condition. I hope you understand that &&